# Lambda Syntax for Joins via Navigation Property?

Tags: c#, linq

I can perform a join using a navigation property, which to me is more DRY because I'm not repeating the join criteria everywhere:

```
(from c in db.Companies
from e in c.Employees
select new { Employee = e, Company = c}).ToList();
```

Because the ORM knows how Companies is related to Employees, the `c.Employees` navigation property is used to infer the FK criteria for the join.

**What is the direct translation to extension/lambda syntax of a multiple from clause via navigation property?**

I know there is a Join extension method, but requires you explicitly name the FK's being compared, rather than it imply that criteria by the navigation property.   This is non-working but hopefully expresses my intent:

```
db.Companies
  .Join(c.Employees, /* don't want to explicitly name FKs*/)
  .Select(x => new { Employee = x.e, Company = x.c}).ToList();
```

Of course `Join(c.Employees` doesn't work because there is no `c` in this context, but idea being somehow use the Companies.Employees navigation property to imply the join criteria.

I know I can do:

```
db.Companies.Select(c => new { Employees = c.Employees, Company = c })
```

but that is a different result set, as it returns one record per company, and then the list of employees as a nested property.  Rather than the first which is a join, thus there is a record for every related combination, and the result has a `Employee` property instead of a `Employees` collection.

I'm not sure, but guessing `.SelectMany` is the direct translation.  You don't get a `c` reference to the parent, so if you do multiple of these:

```
db.Companies.SelectMany(c=>c.Employees).SelectMany(e=>e.VacationDays).Select(v => new { VacationDay = v, Employee = v.Employee, Company = v.Employee.Company })
```

You have to walk backwards across the relationships to flatten out the join. In linq it's much simpler because you would have `c`, `e` and `v` all in the context of the select.  I don't know if you can express the same thing in extension methods, such that all three alias/references are passed down.  Maybe just a consequence of the extension method syntax, but hoping someone will provide a better equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SelectMany` is indeed what multiple `from` clauses are mapped into.

In order to keep variables in scope the projection each `SelectMany` needs to project the sequence into a new anonymous object that keeps all of the appropriate variables in scope:

```
var query = db.Companies.SelectMany(company => company.Employees, 
    (company, employee) => new
{
    company,
    employee
});
```

To add additional projections for additional nested navigation properties, simply repeat the pattern with a subsequent call to `SelectMany`:

```
var query = db.Companies.SelectMany(company => company.Employees,
    (company, employee) => new
{
    company,
    employee
}).SelectMany(pair => pair.employee.VacationDays,
    (pair, vactionDay) => new
{
    pair.company,
    pair.employee,
    vactionDay,
});
```

See [this blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2014/07/31/transparent-identifiers-part-one/) for some more details and an in-depth description of this transformation, and how it scales.

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it just something like:

```
db.Employees.Select(m => new { Employee = m, Company = m.Company });
```

As each employee has a Company, why don't just add navigation property "Company" to Employee entity?

To get vacations, just change it to the following:

```
 db.Employees.SelectMany(
 employee => employee.VacationDays, 
 (employee, vacationDay) => new 
  { 
      Employee = employee, 
      Company = employee.Company, 
      VacationDay = vacationDay 
  });
```

Update:

Actually, there is no difference between:

```
(from c in db.Companies
 from e in c.Employees
 select new { Employee = e, Company = c}).ToList();
```

and:

```
(from e in c.Employees
 from c in db.Companies
 select new { Employee = e, Company = c}).ToList();
```

Comment: He *does* have a navigation property on `Employee` for `Company`.  it's what he's using.  He's trying to use it to project his query into a collection of pairs of an employee and company.  He's doing this just fine using query syntax, but failing to do it using method syntax.  You have not modeled that query syntax query in this answer.

Comment: That's exactly what my query does. I have specified method syntax, just different approach. EF will do correct join, as it does when doing it with a query way.

Comment: I didn't notice you reversed them, but yes, that does do that, although it doesn't answer the question of how the given query syntax query is actually translated into method syntax.

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful to others interested in an alternative approach, but depending on the cardinality of the relationship, doing this kind of thing in the `Select` for anything beyond simple case turns into an exercise in creativity.  Not that Servy's is necessarily always better, I just wanted to have a better understanding of what my LINQ expression represented and see if the direct translation was appealing.

Comment: added little explanation to my answer. For now the only question is "which way is faster?". If you profile result SQL query and post somewhere - that would be great.